# Not able to query UserProfile model in django interactive console

Tags: django, models

I am creating an UserProfile models by extending User model as below,

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # Below line links UserProfile to an User model instance
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # Now add however additional attribues you want to add
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

after this I am going into django interactive shell and querying the above model as below,

```
UserProfile.objects.all()
```

I am expecting that by running this I will get an empty set as I have not added anything.

But I am getting the below error,

**UserProfile not defined**

How do I fix this?

Comment: This is just basic Python: before you can use a class you need to import it.

Comment: you need to import it on your console: `from models import UserProfile`

Comment: my mistake. Always forget the basic stuff :)